# Optional routes with routeEnhancers in TYPO3

Tags: routes, typo3, typo3-10.x

I am struggling to get the following routes of a TYPO3 plugin to work:

1. `example.com/page/` -> not working!
2. `example.com/page/a-z/a/` -> working
3. `example.com/page/a-z/a/more/2/` -> working
4. `example.com/page/page-2/` -> not working!

The URI looks like this:

`example.com/page?tx_myextension_list[controller]=MyController&tx_myextension_list[currentPage]=2&tx_myextension_list[selectedLetter]=&cHash=6258466362eee8ea43be8634002c883f`

My error:

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\InvalidParameterException: Parameter "uf29714be1a983f4b1a864d48e1b6ae" for route "tx_myextension_list_1" must match "[a-zA-Z]{1}" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.

If I remove the empty parameter `tx_myextension_list[selectedLetter]` URL 1 is working, but URL 3 looks like this URL 4 and behaves like this.

This is my configuration:

```
routeEnhancers:
  MyPluginList:
    type: Extbase
    extension: MyExtension
    plugin: list
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/a-z/{letter}'
        _controller: 'MyController::list'
        _arguments:
          letter: 'selectedLetter'
      -
        routePath: '/a-z/{letter}/more/{page}'
        _controller: 'MyController::list'
        _arguments:
          letter: 'selectedLetter'
          page: 'currentPage'
      -
        routePath: 'page-{page}'
        _controller: 'MyController::list'
        _arguments:
          page: 'currentPage'
    defaultController: 'MyController::list'
    requirements:
      letter: '^[a-zA-Z]{1}'
      page: '\d+'
    defaults:
      letter: ''
      page: '0'
    aspects:
      page:
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '100'
      letter:
        type: StaticValueMapper
        map:
          a: A
          b: B
          c: C
          d: D
          e: E
          f: F
          g: G
          h: H
          i: I
          j: J
          k: K
          l: L
          m: M
          n: N
          o: O
          p: P
          q: Q
          r: R
          s: S
          t: T
          u: U
          v: V
          w: W
          x: X
          y: Y
          z: Z
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot a "/" at:

```
routePath: 'page-{page}'
_controller: 'MyController::list'
_arguments:
    page: 'currentPage'
```

Thus "example.com/page/page-2/" wong get generated.

Also have a look at the documentation for the requirements: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html#aspect-precedence
You dont need to add the requirements for the letters if you are using a map for them.

Another problem should be the default value for your letter. Because an empty string isnt matching your requirements/map.

Thats what the error is telling you:

```
must match "[a-zA-Z]{1}" ("" given)
```